# Ubuntu 16:04 LTS: Is there a "maximum resident set size" equivalent when it comes to swap space?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory

I use `/usr/bin/time -v` to get some information about an application that I am running.

```
Command being timed: "./a"
User time (seconds): 0.00
System time (seconds): 0.00
Percent of CPU this job got: 0%
Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:00.12
Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
Average stack size (kbytes): 0
Average total size (kbytes): 0
Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 4652
Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 202
Voluntary context switches: 3
Involuntary context switches: 1
Swaps: 0
File system inputs: 0
File system outputs: 0
Socket messages sent: 0
Socket messages received: 0
Signals delivered: 0
Page size (bytes): 4096
Exit status: 0
```

If I understand correctly, the maximum resident set size corresponds to the maximum RAM that the application required during its execution. I have an application that uses 100% of RAM a lot of swap space, and would like to print something equivalent for that. Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you think you cannot use *time* with this other program?

Comment: Is that not like maxium res set size + (202*Pagesize) ?

Comment: @djsmiley2k No, because minor page faults aren't associated with disk I/O. And it's not the major page faults either because some pages may never have faulted back in and some may have faulted in more than once. (Assuming he wants to know the maximum amount of RAM+swap actually used by the application.)